# NSMutableArray not populating TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hello I'm hoping to work through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13) to learn how to recreate one of my most favorite apps: Clear App by RealMac software.

But I am literally stuck at the beginning. After the first section, before even styling the rows, the tableView is not being populated by the NSMutableArray made in the initWithNibName.

All my code is EXACTLY the same but when I run it I am getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:     'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/DD956F2E-26A7-4357-BCD7-DC0C42939861/Clear App Tutorial.app> (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController''
```

Is there anything that could be missing from the code that is a difference of versions from when the tutorial was made and with Xcode 5 now?

Like do I need to "release" or "addToSubView" the _toDoListItems array in the viewDidLoad method?

Sorry, I am very new to Objective-C and so far it is a big headache for me. :-/

This is in my AppDelegate.m:

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;

    }
    ....etc. and @end
```

And this is in my AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Comment: Did you try the sample project ? `http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/downloads/ClearStyle1Final.zip`

Comment: Also you are trying to load a xib called UIViewController, which does not exist. That's what that error is trying to tell you.

Comment: I'm using the main storyboard for iphone, which is different I know from the tutorial but all except for that I followed the instructions. I have also literally copied the code from the final into mine and I'm getting the same error with all his code. :-/

Comment: I literally started over and I get the error without any other code, it has something to do with having something wrong in the AppDelegate files.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code I am going to assume you are doing this in the appDelegate:

```
[[SHCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Where as you should be doing this:

```
[[SHCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SHCViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Well, I have them just named ViewController, because I opted out of the prefixes. But yes those are in the AppDelegate.m.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell exact reason, but I can see your app delegate is inheriting from UIResponder, which does not require anything to be done to show UIWindow (no initWithNibName, no call to makeKeyAndVisible).

You need to ensure that:
1. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method just needs to return YES.
2. On the storyboard, for the ViewController is "is initial view controller" is checked in the  attributes inspector (So that it becomes first screen shown after launch of app).

That may fix the problem. Let me know whether it works.

Other possible reason could be (as exception name suggests) any inconsistency in the references to the files, try removing all files and adding them again.

Comment: It seem that answer was useful to you as it is up voted. I am equally curious to know, what was useful out of it, the first reason or the second one? :) Also, if this resolved your issue, please tick the checkmark next to it (as correct answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is very common issue with UIs check whether you have created two outlets for same UIElement(button,tableview etc)... delete that by right clicking on UIElement....
For eg,

Make sure there is only one referencing outlet for everyView if there is more than one delete the extra one
[image]

Comment: @Magdalene B. hope this helps

Comment: I'm still stuck unfortunately, just going back through the tutorial itty-bitty step-by-step. Thank you, I did check and I only have one reference outlet assigned and that is tableView-->ViewController.